# Missing index configuration firestore Spring Boot

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud-gcp

I'm trying to run a custom query for spring data firestore.
In my FirestoreReactiveRepository I created:

```
findAllBySubTypeOrderByOccurredAt(String subType);
```

and I created the indexes in firestore:

```
subType:ASC  occurredAt:ASC
```

But when I run the code I have the error:

> FAILED_PRECONDITION: Missing index configuration. Please create corresponding index via gcloud.

Comment: There is no call to Firestore in the code you shared, but from the error message it seems that you're missing a required index. If you search for that error message, you should find how to fix this. Or check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing. If that doesn't allow you to fix it, show the exact call you make to the Firestore API.

Comment: That is the problem, I'm not able to see the call spring does to database. The logs are not showing, even with the right config. I will try to get this logs right to be able to get the call. Will post here If I get it.

Comment: If you don't know the actual query that's being made, you don't have a very good chance of creating the index required to satisfy it.  You need to know the fields used in the query - filters and ordering - in order to make an index for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I still don't know how to see the query but the problem was that the model I used as the entity has the field occurredAt as sql.TimeStamp and I needed to use the com.google.Timestamp type.
It worked to save into database but it was messed up to create the query with the indexes. Thank you for your help frank-van-puffelen